# Encoding options for SMS delivery that contains Norwegian and other Scandinavian characters

Tags: android, ios, character-encoding, sms

I'm developing a process in eCircle that sends SMS messages to users in Norway but that may later be used in Finland, Denmark, and Sweden (this is a trial process).

Unfortunately, I am unable to deliver Norwegian characters to users with iPhones when using ISO-8859-1 encoding. Test users that have non-smartphones seem to be getting the characters fine, but users with iOS 6 and iOS 7 are not able to see them. I can confirm that users of at least newer HTC Android devices also receive the characters, so it seems to focus on iOS.

Unfortunately, using UTF-8 is out of the question, because it only allows us 70 characters and we need around 150-155. And we don't want to use multiple messages, because that would get very expensive for the client.

I've attempted UTF-16 and ISO-8859-15 but SMS doesn't support these encodings. So, I'm left to wonder what other encodings exist that might support Norwegian characters specifically, and Scandinavian characters in general?

Comment: hi, have a look at this discussion: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1030577

Comment: `UTF-8 allows only 70 characters`. No. It depends on the characters. Most norwegians characters are in the ascii range, hence encoded on 1 byte. UTF-16, on the other hand, encodes all characters on at least 2 bytes, effectively resulting in having less than 70 characters max. As for `SMS doesn't support these encodings`, do you have a source to back that statement?

Comment: I could be mistaken - it could be that the system we use doesn't support these encodings for SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was a configuration problem with our SMS Gateway provider. Specifically, they were not using UCS-2 configurations.

Answer (score 0):

SMS supports 3 encodings:

1. 7bits GSM_03.38. Mostly ASCII chars, plus a few in an extra table.
2. 16bits UCS-2, which is similar to UTF-16, but uses only 16bits chars, not 32bits chars. It supports most of the characters you can encounter in the world
3. 8bits raw. The actual encoding is user specific. I have no idea what it actually does

Now, there is a field in the sms protocol (`Data Coding Scheme`) that is used to indicate the language of the sms. Apparently it is not really used, but it would make sense if a phone could use it to infer the encoding of the 8bit sms.

Nota: Even in 8bits, you'll get only 140 chars, not 160.